# Elixir: Is there any benefit of using & operator to get an anonymous function out of a named function

Tags: elixir, operators, anonymous-function

So I was reading this book and at some point it states that :

> There’s a second form of the & function capture operator. You can give
>   it the name and arity (number of parameters) of an existing function,
>   and it will return an anonymous function that calls it.

But I don't understand why would somebody want to do this. What is the benefit one can get out of it, knowing that you can can bound both named and unnamed function to variables if you want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty common to have some simple functions like

```
Enum.map(list, fn(element) -> element.id end)
```

Or just

```
Enum.map(list, &(&1.id))
```

With some practice, second one is even easier to read than the first

Regarding your question, you can also call a named function in the same way

```
Enum.map(list, &Integer.to_string/1)
```

Alternative is to pass a function to the Enum using `fn`

```
Enum.map(list, fn(number) -> Integer.to_string(number) end)
```

Also, captured variant is easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

The book is incorrect.  `&MyModule.my_function/0` does *not* return "an anonymous function that calls the given function" - it returns a function object that refers to the named function.  To get an anonymous function, you'd use `fn -> MyModule.my_function() end`.

This becomes important when you reload modules at runtime: an anonymous function is part of the module it was created in, and since only two versions of a given module are kept in the virtual machine (the "current" and the "old" version), you could end up with a function that can't be called anymore.

Let's start with this module:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def the_real_function() do
    2
  end

  def anonymous_function() do
    fn -> __MODULE__.the_real_function() end
  end

  def named_function() do
    &__MODULE__.the_real_function/0
  end
end
```

It contains the function we're actually interested in, and two functions that return functions that refer to the real function - one with an anonymous function, one with a named function object.

Let's load the module, get two function objects, and check that we can call them:

```
iex(1)> c "my_module.ex"
[MyModule]
iex(2)> f_anon = MyModule.anonymous_function()
#Function<0.62651516/0 in MyModule.anonymous_function/0>
iex(3)> f_named = MyModule.named_function()
&MyModule.the_real_function/0
iex(4)> f_anon.()
2
iex(5)> f_named.()
2
```

So far so good.  Now, let's say we need to update the module, so that the function returns 3 instead.  We edit the module and reload it:

```
iex(6)> c "my_module.ex"
warning: redefining module MyModule (current version defined in memory)
  my_module.ex:1

[MyModule]
iex(7)> f_anon.()
3
iex(8)> f_named.()
3
```

Our function references still work - good.  Say we need to update the module again, to return 4:

```
iex(9)> c "my_module.ex"
warning: redefining module MyModule (current version defined in memory)
  my_module.ex:1

[MyModule]
iex(10)> f_anon.()
** (BadFunctionError) expected a function, got: #Function<0.62651516/0 in MyModule>

iex(10)> f_named.()
4
```

Now the anonymous function is broken!  That's because we got a reference to it two module versions back, and therefore the code for this anonymous function is no longer kept in the VM.  The named function reference still works, because it just refers to the function with the given module, name and arity.